# IOS Code Signing Debugging Utility

Tags: ios, certificate, code-signing, keychain, public-key

I'm looking at creating a standalone utility that displays user friendly 
error messages for debugging issues related to code signing and deployment 
that are typically encountered during IOS development.

It should programatically start by opening a provisioning profile chosen by 
the user, inspect each of the certificates in them, dig out the public 
key used in each of the certificates, find out if the appropriate private 
keys are present in the key-chain and then see if the raw materials are
in the right places. If something is missing or out of place it should 
display very a clear message to the user. If all is fine, it should 
display the certificate to use along with the chosen private key from
the key-chain.

To achieve this, how would I programatically extract the public keys 
from inside the certificates and inspect the key-chain for private key 
matches? Any pointers would help.

PS: I know XCode does some of the above but it is not as 
friendly as it should be and the I think mysteries related to the black box
code-signing approach needs to be unraveled and democratized.

Comment: You're right in the last point, but that will never happen, since it is the key in the DRM of apps.

Comment: H2CO3, Just to be clear -  I'm not interested in getting holds of Apple's private keys that are used to sign apps for the app store or break their DRM - it is the code signing process that needs a good technical description in terms of how it works under the covers... I'm not interested in breaking encryption of any sort - but more interested in  building a utility that helps debug code signing issues. thx!

Comment: @userXXX Oh, I see! What you are looking for is the [source code of Saurik's `ldid` utility.](http://gitweb.saurik.com/ldid.git/tree)

Comment: H2CO3, it is getting warmer...

Comment: @userXXX That's a link in my comment, did you see it? :)

Comment: Oh yes - thanks for the link! On a different note, from the IOS hackers handbook, I extracted the following mechanism that helped me get the developers id - Open the provisioning profile, extract the developer certificate - it is the data present in the <data> element. Cut and paste it into a document. Add the following prefix "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and suffix "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" to the data (leave out the "'s) Save it in a file - temp.txt - and run "openssl x509 -in temp.txt -text" - this spits out the developers id:) Next is to access the keychain ...